# How can I pass a long int to itoa function?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I tried changing the parameter type of `__value` to long long int which did not (as expected) change anything.

```
char   *_CType itoa(long long int __value, char *__string, int __radix);
```

Since I am using ancient C++ (the one used even before standard C++), please suggest some alternative method if there is nothing I can do about this as `itoa` might be defined in the compiler.

Note: I am trying to pass a string (*char) to outtextxy function.

The IDE I am currently using TURBO C++.

Comment: `snprintf()`. Or if that's too new, `sprintf()`. But, really, you **need** a modern compiler, not one that's been obsolete for going on 25 years.

Comment: I am trying to pass a string (*char) to `outtextxy` function

Comment: Is there any valid reason to use an ancient compiler?

Comment: @machine_1 maintaining legacy code where you don't have permission to, or flat-out can't, change the compiler.

Comment: @SonofStackoverflow looks like you changed the declaration for the function in the header. The compiled library that implements the function has no idea that you did this.

Comment: @user4581301 Even I feel the same...Is there any alternative method to convert an int to string(/*char)?

Comment: Look up at @Shawn 's comment.

Comment: @hyde Yes, you can use it by including stdlib.h header file in your program code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `itoa` function is part of the C standard library, and you can not change the type of parameter it receives.

However, the C "standard" library is not really standard, it is supplied with your compiler and / or OS, and will have some differences depending on the version of said compiler / OS.

Looking around on Google, it is possible that you have access to a different function called [`ltoa`](http://www.kev.pulo.com.au/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cstdlib/ltoa.html).

Alternatively, depending on what functionality you actually need, coding your own version of this function may be fairly easy.
For example, if you do not need the `base` parameter and always want to work with decimal integers, the code to convert them to string is trivial, and often given as a basic programming exercise.